# Conda env Spyder Python interpreter ipython kernel crash

Tags: python, spyder

I have a python 2.7 environment set up in Conda, and when launching Spyder it uses the system default python interpreter: Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:09:15)

After telling it to use the python interpreter that the environment is using: Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec  4 2017, 23:37:59) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2

The ipythonkernel crashes repeatedly. Maybe the reason is because it's launching spyder3 and not spyder2?

Any suggestions?

Edit* Crash code added:

> File "/home/fosa/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site‑packages/spyder/utils/ipython/start_kernel.py", line 212, in main
>   from utils.ipython.spyder_kernel import SpyderKernel
>   ImportError: No module named ipython.spyder_kernel
>   Traceback (most recent call last):

Edit 2* Here is the path of the python interpreter causing the issue

> /home/fosa/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow2/bin/python

Comment: it would be easier to diagnose if you would cut and paste the code or commands you  and the actual crash msg

Comment: Right, duh, thanks :)

Comment: Do you have a module called `utils` in your current working directory?